# Re-indexing the arrays numerically

Tags: php

How can i remove `NULL` values in an array with its index and reassign the index to other values in order?

```
Array
(
    [1] => 115,2010-02-17,19:30
    [3] => 400,2006-03-01,22:00
    [4] => 474,2006-04-10,02:30
    [5] => 7547,2006-08-02,23:16
)
```

But what i need is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 115,2010-02-17,19:30
    [2] => 400,2006-03-01,22:00
    [3] => 474,2006-04-10,02:30
    [4] => 7547,2006-08-02,23:16
)
```

Comment: check this link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
<?php
$array=array(0=>"a",3=>"b");
$b=array_values($array);
print_r($b);
//displays Array ( [0] => a [1] => b ) 
?>
```

More info [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$new = array_values($array_with_holes);
```

PS: actually there are no `NULL` values in your array, it's just an array with sparse keys

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1=Array();
//here assign array value to $linksArray
foreach ($array1as $key => $link)
{
    if ($array1[$key] == '')
    {
        unset($array1[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what OP meant. He wants to re-index the array keys